# ROOT conditional branch selection

Tags: c++, linux, root-framework

I have a ROOT file. I can read the tree and select the data inside a specific branch of it, called for instance "branch_name_1". Now, I want to select the data on this branch with a specific condition on another branch. Let me provide an example. I want all entries of the "branch_name_1" with the condition that the value of "branch_name_2" is bigger than 10. How can I do this?

**EDIT**: I actually have a tree named "tree", two branches "b1" and "b2". Symbolically, I want to obtain the Standard deviation of the "b1"'s histogram over different values of "b2". For instance, where "b1>1", "b1>2", and so on.

Comment: How are you trying to access the branches? It's hard to guess without an explicit example. if you are using `TTree::Draw`, then you can specify the selection `TCut` as an argument, see [doc](https://root.cern.ch/doc/master/classTTree.html). If you're looping on the tree entries, you probably want to use a [TEventList](http://root.cern.ch/root/html/TEventList.html)

Comment: @user2148414 I edited my question. please take a look

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure this is what you're asking, but anyway:

```
tree.Draw("b1 >> h01(100, -10, +10)", "b2 > 1.0")
tree.Draw("b1 >> h02(100, -10, +10)", "b2 > 2.0")
tree.Draw("b1 >> h03(100, -10, +10)", "b2 > 3.0")
print("b1 RMS for b2 > 1.0: ",h01.GetRMX())
print("b1 RMS for b2 > 2.0: ",h02.GetRMX())
print("b1 RMS for b2 > 3.0: ",h03.GetRMX())
```